# php-fpm SERVER_NAME sub-domains using NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

*In my PHP app:*

```
die($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

*The request:*

```
sub1.example.com
```

*The result:*

```
example.com
```

*My NGINX config:*

```
server
{
    server_name .example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        if ($request_filename ~ /sub1) {
            rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com/? permanent;
        }
        if ($request_filename ~ /sub2) {
            rewrite ^ http://sub2.example.com/? permanent;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why is the sub-domain not being picked up in php?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is the name of the virtual host, which is `.example.com` in your nginx config. You'll want `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` if you want the hostname from the request regardless of the nginx server_name value.

Comment: This worked for me, awsome! I have a quick follow up question I've posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/496609/nginx-location-clause-for-only-root-domain