# NGINX location clause for only root domain

Tags: nginx

How do I only redirect too `sub1.example.com` when hitting `$request_filename ~ /sub1` on `example.com`. For example if I'm on `sub1.example.com`, hitting `/sub1` wont redirect me back too `sub1.example.com` but rather the actual page `sub1.example.com/sub1`?

*My NGINX config:*

```
server
{
    server_name .example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        if ($request_filename ~ /sub1) {
            rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com/? permanent;
        }
        if ($request_filename ~ /sub2) {
            rewrite ^ http://sub2.example.com/? permanent;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I use the** `location` **clause for only root domain?**

### [Update @ Marcel:](https://serverfault.com/questions/496609/nginx-location-clause-for-only-root-domain#answer-496625)

```
server
{
    server_name .example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /sub1 {
       if($host = "example.com") {
           rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com permanent;
       }
    }
    location = /sub2 {
       if($host = "example.com") {
           rewrite ^ http://sub2.example.com permanent;
       }
    }
    location / {
       if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: still no luck? no progress on this matter?

Comment: @Marcel Afraid not. Using your latest configuration I am still running into the case where "a request to `http://sub1.example.com/sub1` still redirects the user to `http://sub1.example.com`".

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `If` inside `Location` block. much better to declare several sections `server {}` in config with different `server_name`.

Instead `if (-f $request_filename) {` use `try_files` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx treats location directives in a certain manner, depending on which directives you have. [This link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) points out nginx behaviour:

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression.
>   Regular expressions are specified by prepending them with the “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or with the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching).
>
> To find a location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the most specific one is searched.
>   Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in a configuration file. A search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used.
>
> If no match with a regular expression is found then a configuration of the most specific prefix location is used."

`location /` is a wildcard location that will match every request.

This is what your locations should be:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
location = /sub1 {
   if($host = "example.com") {
       rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com permanent;
   }
}
location = /sub2 {
   if($host = "example.com") {
       rewrite ^ http://sub2.example.com permanent;
   }
}
location / {
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer however it doesn't seem to be working as intended. I'm still redirected back too each subdomain index for those location directives. Are you able to reproduce?

Comment: You're saying that a request to `http://sub1.example.com/sub1` still redirects the user to `http://sub1.example.com` using only the `location` directives I've pointed out?

Comment: Correct, yes. I've updated my post to what my updated config is currently.

Comment: @Marcel You have a syntax error. `location = ` is used for literal matching, `^` and `$` are meta-characters of _regular expressions_ and missplaced. My edit should fix this. You should also consider replacing regular expressions by literal matches wherever possible (would probably improve performance).

Comment: The nginx wiki also advises the use of `try_files` over `ìf` (regarding the `location /` block): [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#What_to_do_instead). This is a minor issue, however, since `rewrite` can safely be used inside `if`.